# Jenkinsfile withSonarQubeEnv Finished: FAILURE after successfull execution of steps

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

We have a jenkins pipeline job that fails after succesful execution of all the stages.

The pipeline is called sonartest, it gets a jenkinsfile sonar.jenkins from git.

The sample script is the result of stripping our real jenkinsfile down to the part that cause the issue. In the real jenkinsfile there is parallel execution of several sonar scans inside the withSonarQubeEnv. The scans themselves are all successful, in the sample I replaced them with a simple dir statement .

The pipeline gives no error if I remove the withSonarQubeEnv.

### sample

```
def nodelabel = "windows"
def applroot = "C:\\temp\\"

node(nodelabel) {
        stage('SonarQube training analysis') {
            withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {

                dir("${applroot}") {
                      bat "dir"
                }

            }
        }
}
```

### console output

```
Started by user 
Obtained buildfiles/sonar.jenkins from git ssh://git:7999/gitest/jenkinsbuildtest.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on hostname in C:\workspaces\jenkins\workspace\sonartest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (SonarQube training analysis)
[Pipeline] withSonarQubeEnv
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: SonarQube
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in C:\temp
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat

C:\temp>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9E5D-D8F8

 Directory of C:\temp

18/02/2019  15:00    <DIR>          .
18/02/2019  15:00    <DIR>          ..

// trimmed

            8061 File(s)     80ÿ494ÿ243 bytes
              21 Dir(s)  130ÿ154ÿ577ÿ920 bytes free
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from hostname/XXX.XXX.XXX.31:61231
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:389)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:957)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1068)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1057)
        at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1891)
        at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1875)
        at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1860)
        at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarUtils.extractReportTask(SonarUtils.java:84)
        at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarUtils.addBuildInfoTo(SonarUtils.java:111)
        at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarBuildWrapper$AddBuildInfo.tearDown(SonarBuildWrapper.java:170)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep$Callback.finished(CoreWrapperStep.java:152)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep$Execution2$Callback2.finished(CoreWrapperStep.java:122)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution$TailCall.lambda$onSuccess$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:140)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.io.IOException: C:\workspaces\jenkins\workspace\sonartest does not exist.
    at hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1931)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$3200(FilePath.java:209)
    at hudson.FilePath$ListGlob.invoke(FilePath.java:1905)
    at hudson.FilePath$ListGlob.invoke(FilePath.java:1893)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3041)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:210)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:358)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for this issue. 
When I put the `withSonarQubeEnv` within `dir("${applroot}") {}` .
In the simplified sample the inner dir is no longer required, in my real world script there are multiple, different, parallel executed sonarscans in different directories.

### Work around

```
def nodelabel = "windows"
def applroot = "C:\\temp\\"

node(nodelabel) {
    stage('SonarQube training analysis') {
        dir("${applroot}") {
            withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
                dir("${applroot}") {
                     bat "dir"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```